# Применение стилей в зависмости от элемента массива

Tags: php, javascript

Есть массив с вариантами доставок.

```
<div class="block_delivery_order">
        <ul class="b-var-list">
    foreach ($arResult["DELIVERY"] as $delivery_id => $arDelivery){
      var_dump($arDelivery["SID"]); //выводит [1],[2],[3],[4].
      <li class="b-item">
          .....
       </li>
    }
      </ul>
</div>
```

Нужно для [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AscnY.png) и [3] применять `<div class="block_delivery_order">` , а для [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN4hp.png) и [4] `<div class="block_delivery_order_left">`
Может js как-то поможет?
Вот скрины разметки сейчас и что должно получится:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы хотите выставлять класс контейнеру в зависимости от цикла который идет внутри? но в нем же сами написали 1,2,3,4 - и все внутри как вы будете выбирать?

Comment: @Grundy да, вот я и спрашиваю можно ли как-то выбрать)

Comment: а можете конечный пример разметки привести? сейчас просто непонятно, что именно в итоге должно получиться

Comment: @Grundy добавил скрины

Comment: а чем картинки отличаются? я что-то в разметке разницы не вижу, везде: `block_delivery_order`

Comment: как это вообще работать должно? когда что-то выбрали - что-то должно поменяться? или сразу как-то?

Comment: block_delivery_order margin_delivery_order добавляется для других элементов, должно сразу стоять, как на втором скрине.

Comment: Перебирать массив и добавлять значения в разные колонки, в зависимости от SID

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32778/discussion-between-grundy-and-).

Answer (score 1):

Может поможет остаток от деления если key%2 == 0 то собственно это 2 и 4 иначе 1 и 3

Comment: а как вы изнутри цикла проставите класс контейнеру? ведь класс нужно поставить _div_ а цикл - внутри него

Comment: Можно разбить на два массива Order и OrderLeft и выводить в разных div